# Converting string to TimeSpan type

Tags: c#

I have method which the datatype is TimeSpan. How can I convert it to a string?

This is my Model code:

```
private TimeSpan starttime;

    public TimeSpan ShiftStartTime
    {
        get { return starttime; }
        set
        {
            starttime = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ShiftStartTime");
        }
    }
```

This is my ViewModel code:

```
ShiftStartTime = ??reader[3].ToString()
```

The `reader` here represents my MySqlDataReader.

Comment: What's your db timespan data? seconds? miliseconds? minute?

Comment: @Mac Actually now there isnt any data in my db yet. But as per the requirement, this is the format of the Time mysql datatype which is stored in the db "HH:mm:ss"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your time format is "HH:mm:ss" then you can simply do:

```
ShiftStartTime = TimeSpan.Parse(reader[3].ToString());
```

If for example the value in your db is "20:30:21" then the `TimeSpan` object will store:

- Hours: 20
- Minutes: 30
- Seconds: 21

Comment: Question: since you are reading from the DB should you not be using the `TryParse(...)`, for managing the null reference exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime.ParseExact() method as below. You can pass format accordingly.

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.ParseExact(
                                  reader[3].ToString(),
                                  "HHmmss",
                                  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
                                  ).TimeOfDay;
```